# How to add responsive media query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

This is a sample code  , but i cant add responsive .How to add my code for responsive media query ?

```
<form action="action_page.php">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the css3 responsive media query you have to add like this

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
body {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: The code I have given is just an example ... you just have to add you responsive media query inside style